# Objective C property passed reset to null after use

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my root view controller (named rootViewController.h) I have a property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *contactList;
```

Im trying to store value in this dictionary. Im passing the property to my function

```
AddContact *addContact = [[AddContact alloc]init];
NSString *result = @"";
result = [addContact addContact:user :[self contactList]];
```

When I go to my AddContact Function and breakpoint, the contactList is null even though I added 5x on the contactList using this code.

```
User *newUser = [[User alloc]init];
newUser.name = user.name;
newUser.phoneNumber = user.phoneNumber;
newUser.companyName = user.companyName;
[contactList setValue:newUser forKey:newUser.name];
```

Help

Comment: [addContact addContact:user :[self contactList]];
this function seems not formatted correctly, can u paste the function definition line ?

Comment: Function definition added.

Comment: definition line like `- (void)addContact:(User *)user FromDicit:(NSDictionary *)dict;` does your definition look like this ?

Comment: Why are you using `setValue:forKey:`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `NSMutableDictionary`, if you want to change it. `NSDictionary` can't be edited after initialization.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your dictionary you need to create is as mutable like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *contactList;
```

as per rule if you are using Mutable objects you need to alloc ,init it

so  in view's didLoad method

```
_contactList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise contactList. You have not initialise contactList and so the value is not set. And you can use mutable dictionary if you want to change values later on. Please make sure the values being added to contactList are not null else they will not be added to contactList and so dictionary will not have any objects in it.